# Can anybody concate this A[] and B[] to array C[]?

Tags: java, arrays

I did mistake in writing below code but I am not getting the result of C[] as I want to see both A[] and B[] values in C[] ! As you can see in below code that i have try but not succeed.

```
public class ascending {

/**
 * @param args
 */
//@SuppressWarnings("null")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int A [] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int B [] = {6,7,8,9,10};
    int C[] = null;


    int la = A.length;
    int lb = B.length;
    int lc = A.length + B.length;

    System.out.print("ARRAYS in A: ");

    for(int x = 0; x<la;x++){
        System.out.print("  "+A[x]);
    }

    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.print
    ("ARRAYS in B: ");


    for(int y=0;y<lb;y++){
        System.out.print(" "+B[y]);
    }

    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.print("Arrays in C: ");

    for(int z = 0; z<lc; z++){
        System.out.print(" "+C[z]);
    }


    }


}
```

Comment: You never fill out your `C array`.

Comment: Or indeed initialize the `C` variable to have a non-null value at all...

Comment: you need to initialize c = new int[lc]; and fill it up

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("null")` yeah, definitely don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another alternative, by making C a 2D array, you can iterate easier and no extra space will be spent.

```
int[][] C = {A,B};

for(int i=0; i < C.length; i++)
{
   for( int j=0; j < C[i].length; j++)
        System.out.println(C[i][j]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You neither

- allocate the `C` array with `int[] C = new int[size]`
- copy elements in `C` through `C[x] = A[y]` or `C[x] = B[y]`

Actually you never use `C` at all, that's why you don't get any exception: if you would have tried accessing the array you would have got a `NullPointerException` (since C in your current snippet is `null`)

Answer (score 2):

> to see both `A[]` and `B[]` values in C[]

To see those values in `C[]`, you have to do two things:

1. Allocate memory for `C[]`.
2. Copy the elements of `A[]` and `B[]` into `C[]`.

Since this looks very much like homework, I won't spell out the solution and let you figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution can be:

```
int[] c = ArrayUtils.addAll(a, b);
```

using [Apache Commons Lang library.](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29)